# Server 'remote IP' always returns IP address of the default gateway (router) for hits within the network

Tags: router

I've set up a small webserver on a desktop computer for internal and external use at my company. The company network consists of an [D-Link DSL-6740U router](http://www.dlink.ru/mn/products/3/1349.html) connected to a [TP-Link TL-SG1016 switch](http://www.tp-link.co.il/products/details/?model=TL-SG1016), and all the machines in the office are connected to the switch. The router's IP address is `10.0.0.138` and the desktops are all in the `10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.20 range`. The server happens to be `10.0.0.10`. Additionally, I've forwarded port 80 on the router from external requests to the machine hosting the server. Our external IP address is `1.2.3.4` for purposes of discussion.

I've noticed that all requests originating from the LAN with target the server with our external IP address (`1.2.3.4`) show up in the server as being from IP address `10.0.0.138` (the router) and not from the internal IP address of the desktop making the request. If the the desktop made the request via the address `10.0.0.10` (the LAN address of the server) the we see its LAN address (i.e. `10.0.0.6`).

**Why do all requests made to the external address show as being from `10.0.0.138` (the router) as opposed to being shown as from the LAN address (i.e. `10.0.0.6` or even our external address `1.2.3.4`)?** Is this a router 'feature'? Assuming that I cannot change the router's configuration (actually, I can) is there anything that I could do (either on the server or on the client) to have the IP address show as the originating address on the LAN?

**NOTE:** In the original version of this question, I incorrectly stated that even calls to the server's LAN address would show in the logs as being from `10.0.0.138`. I've since learned to triple-check what my users report to me about how they access the server!

Comment: Whick dlink model?

Comment: When going to the site, if they use DNS, what IP does the DNS address translate to? The public IP of the router or the internal IP of the web server?

Comment: What is the subnet mask of the interfaces on the desktop workstation? Are the "server" and the "desktop" all wired to the same switch?

Comment: I have updated the question with the router model and deleted my previous comments. Thanks.

Comment: Why the sudden downvote? How could I improve the question? I feel that this question addresses a very general and possibly common scenario, for which there exists no current authoritative reference online. Additionally, although applicable to a general audience, it does in fact address a current situation that I'm facing.

Comment: I did not downvote, but home networking questions or questions about consumer networking equipment are off-topic.

Comment: @MikePennington: Thanks. Actually, this is a company network that I've inherited. There are over a dozen machines in addition to the router and switch.

Comment: Fair enough,  but these netgear and TP-LINK devices are off-topic as well.   If this is a corporate network,  I encourage you to upgrade to enterprise network equipment.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider it. The equipment has been adequate for our needs (20-port switch, 10-15 users at various times) but if you suggest that it is not up to the task then I will keep my eye out for issues with the switch and router in the future. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: @dotancohen As you have updated your question, if my answer properly answers it, please accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer to your question "Why do all requests show as being from the router?" is:**

**Because the router is performing NAT.**

We need to flesh out more details if we want to determine why traffic is flowing through the router and being NAT'ed.  It sounds like the clients and the server "should be" on the same subnet, and thus traffic should not be traversing the router and being NAT'ed.

Possible reasons traffic would flow through the router:

- The IP Address/subnet mask configuration of the server and of the client put them on different subnets
- The clients are accessing the server via the external IP address and the router is performing u-turn NAT (Source NAT and Destination NAT)

-- Edit:

To answer the updated question:

**Why do all requests made to the external address show as being from 10.0.0.138 (the router) as opposed to being shown as from the LAN address (i.e. 10.0.0.6 or even our external address 1.2.3.4)?**

This is most certainly because some type of DNAT and SNAT or port forwarding are going on.  It is a feature of the router.

Comment: @dotancohen if you look at this manual pages 54-58 and give more details how your router is configured (DMZ, port forward, etc...) we might be able to explain more. http://www.netcheif.com/downloads/DSL-6740U_Manual_Draft1.0_Lab.pdf